zsh cursor movement slow on long lines with select-word-style bash
To get bash-style word movement in zsh, I added these lines to my .zshrc:
# Set word style to bash-like behavior
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash

This works, but it slows down as I reach the end of long lines (100+ characters). What's the best way to fix this?
To be clear, it's fast at the start of long lines, and slow at the end of them.
